# I need help in PCA results using WEKA Tool

Tags: feature-selection, feature-extraction, pca, weka

I'm working on an experiment using KDD'99 cupset I have 42 features. the paper I 'm comparing with concludes that 3 features with precision  ..% ok are the best subset to identify the attack X.
In my experiment,  I applied 4 different classifier through the PCA.  How to compare between them in order to conclude the number of features used in my experiment ? how to explain my  features in order to say that n features gives higher preciosion.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Can you please edit the question, it's not clear exactly what you are doing and what you need help with.